# Show details(sysinfo) rdp C#

Tags: c#, server, rdp

I'm using AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll for connect Virtual Server;

```
try
{
    rdp.Server = txtServer.Text;
    rdp.UserName = txtUserName.Text;

    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
    secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;
    rdp.Connect();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting", "Error connecting to remote desktop " + txtServer.Text + " Error:  " + Ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Well, now I want to display the hardware specifications in the app, Is it possible?(Like: CPU cores, RAM)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to connect with WMI to that server?  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+wmi+hardware+

Comment: Does this mean I can not use this method to get hardware details? (MSTSCLib.dll) ? tnx

Comment: I don't know, I never tried it nor do I believe that interface was designed for that goal. Maybe you can make it do quack, but a duck does that all by itself ...